# Pods : Xcode Library not found for -lGoogleToolboxForMac

Tags: xcode

Recently I installed `cocoapods` and wanted to add `Firebase analytics` to my app. The first time a published the app worked, but now it started showing me that: Library not found for `-lGoogleToolboxForMac`.

[image: https://www.proeminentcode.com/uploads/media/2017/06/27/ss.png]

[image: https://www.proeminentcode.com/uploads/media/2017/06/27/ss-2.png]

I install again pods but still the same.

What should I do in this case? I mention that I use `VirtualBox`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please ensure successful installation of pods.

Also, after installation close current project `.xcodeproj` and open up `.xcworkspace`.

[image]

Comment: After I made some adjustments in Build Settings, reinstall the pods and open the .xcworkspace it worked. Thanks a lot!