# Can't import dependency installed with Cocoapods

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, flutter

I've installed FBSDK with Cocoapods but can't import it in my AppDelegate.swift file for some reason. The FBSDK kit appears in my Xcode project so I feel like it should be working.
[image]

I'm not an iOS developer by any means, I'm just trying to write a simple native plugin for Flutter SDK. Anyone an idea?

**--Here is what the pod file looks like--**

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

if ENV['FLUTTER_FRAMEWORK_DIR'] == nil
  abort('Please set FLUTTER_FRAMEWORK_DIR to the directory containing Flutter.framework')
end

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Runner
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit'

  # Flutter Pods
  pod 'Flutter', :path => ENV['FLUTTER_FRAMEWORK_DIR']

  if File.exists? '../.flutter-plugins'
    flutter_root = File.expand_path('..')
    File.foreach('../.flutter-plugins') { |line|
      plugin = line.split(pattern='=')
      if plugin.length == 2
        name = plugin[0].strip()
        path = plugin[1].strip()
        resolved_path = File.expand_path("#{path}/ios", flutter_root)
        pod name, :path => resolved_path
      else
        puts "Invalid plugin specification: #{line}"
      end
    }
  end
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
    end
  end
end
```

**---EDIT---**

I''m getting the following error atm: `FBSDKCoreKit.framework: No such file or directory`.When I open the Frameworks folder in xCode, all file names are in red:
[image]
**But that exact folder in Finder is empty**. So I guess that's why the error is showing. The question is how to fix this...

This is what my `embedded binaries` and `linked frameworks and libraries` look like in the project:
[image]

Comment: Please check my answer from this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/44787352/3632832

Comment: add framework to embedded binaries.

Comment: @KKRocks How would one do that?

Comment: select project target and you can see there this option.

Comment: @KKRocks I find this in my Pods project under "Build Phases" but can't seem to find it in my Runner project. Like I said, I'm just trying to make a plugin. The project was pre-created so might be a bit strange :/

Comment: which is your xcode and pod versions?

Comment: Could you provide this part of your project settings https://monosnap.com/file/vhPGv6tdInqrqyIaK4zYxnXSk90DMT ?(Embedded binaries/Linked Frameworks and Libraries)

Comment: Added it to the original question.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

1. Select your Project Target
2. Go to Build Settings.
3. Search for Header Search Paths.
4. Add this value $(SRCROOT)/Pods with recursive, then Xcode will resolve the path for you.

[image]

Comment: In xcode v11 the following worked for me: $(SOURCE_ROOT)/Pods/**

Comment: @BramVanbilsen Thanks a lot - you save my day. I wish I can award you bounty too.

Comment: @bryan Thanks a lot. After a day long of headache, i found the solution. Super!!!

Comment: I have done this still it's not working. Please help.

Comment: I had to make it recursive for the Header search paths.  Also added $(SRCROOT)/Pods to the Framework search paths and also made it recursive before it worked for me

Answer (score 13):

Are you opening the `.xcodeproj` or the `.xcworkspace`? Make sure it is the workspace whenever you install a cocoapod

Answer (score 5):

I'll naively suppose you don't have `use_frameworks!` in you `Podfile`. If that's true, than you have two ways to go from here:

1. In your `Runner-Bridging-Header.h` add `#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>`, remove `import FBSDKCoreKit` from `AppDelegate.swift` and just continue writing the code.
2. Add `use_frameworks!` to your `Podfile` and run `pod install` again. That might bring some other issues, but if that works, than I'd suggest it.

Comment: use_frameworks! is already in there. The other option gives me an error:
    /Users/bramvanbilsen/Desktop/facebook_sign_in/facebook_sign_in/example/ios/Pods/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/Internal/AppEvents/FBSDKAppEvents+Internal.h:19:9: fatal error: 'FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKAppEvents.h' file not found
    #import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKAppEvents.h>

Comment: Can you show your `Podfile`? This looks like some strange path you've sent, considering that your app is called `Runner`

Comment: I added it to my question! The app is actually a plugin for Flutter (framework for by google) to allow iOS users to login with Facebook. So the iOS project is auto generated, that's why it's weird... I got it to work on a fresh new project, but need it to work with this auto generated project as well.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `cocoapods`, it should have generated a `*.xcworkspace` file for you. Open this file instead so your project can see the `FBSDK` installed and has reference to it.

Answer (score 3):

When you install your pods, you must build your application first. Then your imports stop showing errors.

Comment: Not sure why this didn't get more traction. I didn't realize this and running my app instantly allowed me to import the cocoa pods - thanks!

Comment: This answer needs to be higher

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply use the Swift pods?-

```
pod 'FacebookCore'
pod 'FacebookLogin'
pod 'FacebookShare'
```

and then import as normal, like-

```
import FBSDKLoginKit
import FacebookLogin
```

Once done, do a clean and build (<kbd>command/⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>) and Build (<kbd>command/⌘</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>). Make sure you are using the `.xcworkspace` file to open the project.

More info on Swift FBSDK [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift/getting-started).

Once you use the Swift pods, you should see these Frameworks in your project.

[image]

If you still continue to see the error then "Clean the build folder" using <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>.

Comment: But the pods I used worked in a clean new swift project. So I don't see why they should not be working for this one...

Comment: It's up to you what you want to use. Pods are installed per project and there could be many things that might have gone wrong with this project's pod install. Check the targets for the frameworks installed or just try to reinstall the pods (remove pod entry from pod file and run install and then add it again and install).

Answer (score 0):

Start by cleaning your project using `Command + Shift + K` then close the project and delete the `pods` folder and the `pod.lock` file and your `.xcworkspace` file. Then run `pod install` and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: I tried that and after building the project I get the following kind of error for every dependency installed with cocoa pods: 
error: /Users/bramv/Documents/Flutter-Facebook-Sign-In-Plugin/example/ios/build/Debug-iphoneos/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.framework: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

First Clean your project directory. And add $(inherited) in framework search path in Build settings.

Comment: Then add your framework path to your Framework search path. Like Target -> Build Settings -> Framework Search Paths -> "your Local Directory path like "/Users/user/Documents/FacebookSDKs"

Comment: What should this local path directory be? I didn't manually download the sdk like in the old days. That why I am trying to use pods :)

Comment: should  $(inherited) be recursive or non-recursive?

Comment: It's non-recursive

Answer (score 0):

As importing the `FBSDKCoreKit.framework` etc. will be performed in the `[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks` build phase when using CocoaPods, you should remove the references to these frameworks in the `Embed Frameworks` build phase.

CocoaPods will not create those references, I assume you have tried other ways of importing the Facebooks frameworks, and these link have been created in the process. You can also delete the references to the Facebook frameworks in the Frameworks Folder of you App-Project (the ones in your screenshot written in red, not the ones in the Pods-Project!), but keep the `Pods_Runner.framework` there.

From what I can tell, your `Linked Frameworks and Libraries` section looks valid.

If it still doesn't work, I'd advise you to create a new Xcode Project with an empty Podfile, and only include the Facebook frameworks via CocoaPods. Importing the Facebook-SDK in the AppDelegate should work then, otherwise I can share a sample project with you. Then you should check your build setting and build phases, maybe something is wrong there. If you still can't figure out the problem, you will probably need to re-create you xcode-project and import all your files again.

Without a sample Project that reproduces the error, that's the best advise I can give.

Good Luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

The above solutions for Header Search Path should work.
If you are too lazy to go there.
Copy podfile content, remove all pods, pod install, then revert your podfile, pod install again.... Should work ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was correctly installed but I realized the **pod is Objective-C** and couldn't import it on a **Swift file**. I had to create a *bridging header* to make it work.

Refer to this stackoverflow thread
[How to import existing Objective C classes in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24034488/3900793)